# I am having problem in downloading the VS code here is error i am getting i am using macBook pro

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to install Visual Studio Code can anyone please help me.I am adding image please help me out of this.

Comment: Could you add error message and screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Visual studio code cant be opened because apple cannot check it for malicious software

This software need to be updated.Contact the developer for more information.

Comment: sure let me try it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press the right key on the downloaded file, click "Open with" and then click "Installer (default)".